# How to get all children to specific depth in parent child relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, recursion, include

We are using EF code first and have a model with the following structure. There is a requirement to get items to a a certain depth. For example get all job types to a depth of 2 would get all JobTypes with a null parent and their children.

```
namespace My.Models
{
    public class JobType
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public long? ParentJobTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual JobType ParentJobType { get; set; }

        public virtual Collection<JobType> JobTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a requirement to get items to a certain depth. Hint - look at the question tite

Answer (score 1):

You can generate include string and use [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696450(v=vs.103).aspx)

```
var query = ctx.JobType.Where(x => x.ParentJobTypeId == null);

if (count > 0)
{
    var include = string.Join(".", Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(x => "JobTypes"));
    query = query.Include(include);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you explain the "include" line? Or can you tell me that from where it will get "JobTypes" in .Select(x => "JobTypes")

Comment: You can force entity framework to eagerly include related collections in the result. This can be done using `Include` method. You can specify the path to related collections using string or by an Expression. Please read the documents.

Comment: Can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889920/c-get-childs-upto-given-depth?noredirect=1#comment90736659_51889920