# C#- Get childs upto given depth

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a list that contains parent child relation and I want to get children upto defined length:

Given the following class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the list:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Parent", ParentId = 0 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Child1", ParentId = 1 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Child2", ParentId = 1 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 4, Name = "GrandChild1", ParentId = 2 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 5, Name = "GrandChild2", ParentId = 2 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 6, Name = "GrandChild3", ParentId = 3 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 7, Name = "GrandChild4", ParentId = 3 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 8, Name = "GrandGrandChild1", ParentId = 4 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 9, Name = "GrandGrandChild2", ParentId = 5 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 10, Name = "GrandGrandChild3", ParentId = 6 });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 11, Name = "GrandGrandChild4", ParentId = 7 });
```

Now I want that if I pass depth=0 in url then it will return all data but if I pass depth=1 then it will return string like:

```
"Parent:Child1:GrandChild1:GrandGrandChild1"
"Parent:Child1:GrandChild2:GrandGrandChild2"
```

and if I pass depth=2 then:

```
"Parent:Child1:GrandChild1:GrandGrandChild1"
```

I have tried this code:

```
public void Traverse(List<Item> list)
{
    var parentIds = list.Where(e => e.ParentId > 0).Select(e => e.ParentId).ToList();

    var bargs = list.Where(e => !parentIds.Contains(e.Id)).ToList();

    foreach (var item in bargs)
    {
        Traverse(list, item);
    }
}

private void Traverse(List<Item> items, Item item)
{
    var list = new List<Item> { item };

    int id = item.ParentId;

    while (true)
    {
        var found = items.Where(e => e.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        list.Insert(0, found);

        if(found.ParentId == 0) { break; }

        id = found.ParentId;
    }

    var str = string.Empty;
    foreach (var node in list)
    {
        str += node.Name;
        if(node != item) { str += ":"; }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Now this code returns the desired strings successfully but I can't figure out how can I add depth check in "items". Depth can be "n" so I can't add if else. Any help?

Comment: Can you explain your *'depth'* more? Or provide more examples? Why should depth=2 return the **first** GrandGrandChild?

Comment: Abuse Reflection Maybe, Im guessing that might be the best bet.

Comment: you first need to make a tree of the nodes...c# treenode

Comment: Data grouping shall help, but need more clarity in the question, what does `depth=1` or `depth=2` means, like why does depth level 1 includes `GrandGrandChild1` and for that matter why does depth level 2 doesn't include `Parent:Child1:GrandChild2:GrandGrandChild2`, need more clarity

Comment: As far as depth is concerned, max depth is total data count, which can break out of loop, though Dictionary is a better data structure

Comment: Your `depth` explanation doesn't has ambiguous correlation

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the function below :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to get the string representations of the hierarchy List
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Items">The hierarchical list of items</param>
    /// <param name="rootItem">The item whose children are to be traversed</param>
    /// <param name="depth">Depth to which the function should traverse. Passsing zero will make the function traverse throughout the heirarchy</param>
    /// <returns>List of string representing each hierarchy</returns>
    public List<string> GetChildren(List<Item> Items, Item rootItem, int depth)
    {
        List<string> ReturnList = new List<string>();

        TraverseChildren(Items, rootItem, depth, 1, ReturnList, rootItem.Name);

        return ReturnList;
    }

    private void TraverseChildren(List<Item> items, Item rootItem, int depth, int currentLevel, List<string> hierarchyList, string hierarchyString)
    {
        // Return If current level is higher than Depth
        // And depth is non-zero
        if (currentLevel > depth && depth !=0) { return; }

        Item[] Children = items.Where(x => x.ParentId == rootItem.Id).ToArray();

        foreach (Item itm in Children)
        {
            string currentItemHeirarchyString = string.Format("{0}:{1}", hierarchyString, itm.Name);
            hierarchyList.Add(currentItemHeirarchyString);

            TraverseChildren(items, itm, depth, currentLevel + 1, hierarchyList, currentItemHeirarchyString);
        }
    }
```

Sample usage :

```
        // Get the item whose children to be traveresed
        Item RootItem = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Child1");
        GetChildren(list, RootItem, 1);
```

The result will be

```
Child1:GrandChild1
Child1:GrandChild2
```

Comment: Question here is incomplete, to provide an example for depth 1, why would you just list only "Parent:Child1" and "Parent:Child2" why not other depth 1 combinations like "GrandChild1:GrandGrandChild1", you have made an assumption that it shall only be with respect to main root

Comment: The list is storing a hierarchy and with that respect Depth means the level. So if you plot the list on paper the "GrandGrandChild1" will be at 3rd level from the top "Parent". You got the point ?

Comment: Nope, since you are assuming that depth 1 is only in context of the root parent, not for parents at other level. Mostly questions are not so simple that everything is with respect to the parent, that's why i mentioned question is incomplete and you may have to list down the assumption in your answer

Comment: @MrinalKamboj You make a point. I must ask for the root node as an argument. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I've updated the answer to handle the scenario. Thanks 4 ur input .

Comment: Great, certainly deserves an up vote, though my point was even if you are just given the depth, then it shall still list all the relevant combinations, that's little complex, but what you have now achieved is a subset